# Addition of two numbers using constructor with only one parameter

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

Here I need to add two numbers, but my constructor has only one parameter. And it should be has one parameter. Using the addFunc I need to add my two different numbers.

```
int result = 0;
class Num{
  private:
  int a;
  public:
  Num(int a) {
    a = a;
  }
  int getA(){
    return a;
  }
  void setA(int a){
    a = a;
  }
    int addFunc() {
      return result += getA();
    }
  }
};
```

Here is my 'main' function and I need to output the sum of two numbers which is supposed to be saves to 'result' variable.
[image: ![enter image description here]

The problem is that instead of getting the real result 5+6=11 I get this ->
[image]

Comment: `a = a;` does not do what you think it does (and is really confusing on top of that)

Comment: `this->a = a;` or `Num(int a) : a(a) {}` or rename the parameter to avoid confusion.

Comment: The error is pointed out above. But even with the fixes suggested this code makes no sense at all. Don't you think that adding two numbers should be a bit easier to do? I strongly suspect you've misunderstood what you are being asked to do.

Comment: Chances are that in `main` you should evaluate the sum writing something like `int f = num.addFunc(num1);` and change that function signature accordingly.

Comment: What Bob__ suggests make much more sense than what you have written. With that code `addFunc` can access the two numbers which it is supposed to add together (which obviously it need to do). That way you can eliminate the global `result` variable, which I'm sure you are not supposed to be using.

Comment: why do you post `main()` in an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Bob__'s suggestion it seems likely that your code is supposed to look something a bit like this

```
class Num {
private:
    int a;
public:
    Num(int a) {
        this->a = a;
    }
    int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    void setA(int a) {
        this->a = a;
    }
    int addFunc(Num other) {
        return a + other.a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Num num(5);
    Num num2(6);
    cout << num.addFunc(num2);
}
```

As you can see, it's a bit more logical, a bit simpler, and doesn't need to use a global variable to add two numbers togther.

Comment: Maybe use the initializer list in the constructor. Its not much more changes to OPs code than currently and you still have an example of `this->a = a` in `setA`